# irreducible complex representations of group

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the irreducible complex representations of group $<a>_4$

I tried: $<a>_4={e,a,a^2,a^3}$

Comment: Hint: Have you heard of the Quaternion group?

Comment: $<a>_4$ is the ciclic group of order 4, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since $C_4=\{e,a,a^2,a^3\}$ it has 4 1-dimensional complex irreps:

trivial irrep $\rho_1=1$
$$\rho_2(e)=\rho_2(a^2)=1, \rho_2(a)=\rho_2(a^3)=-1$$
$$\rho_3(e)=1, \rho_3(a)=i, \rho_3(a^2)=-1, \rho_3(a^3)=-i$$
$$\rho_4(e)=1, \rho_3(a)=-i, \rho_3(a^2)=-1, \rho_3(a^3)=i$$

Comment: why it has $41 - dimensional$ complex irreps.?